# Issue with deleting object from parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am facing an issue when trying to delete objects from Parse after having queried them.

My code:

```
        var query = PFQuery(className:"sendMessage")
        query.whereKey("messageSent", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
        query.whereKey("messageReceived", equalTo: self.nameLabel!.text!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, NSError) -> Void in

            if  objects != nil {

                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {


                        print(object["message"])

                   /// here I would go: object.deleteInBackground()
                                        object.save()

                      }
                 }
               }
         })
```

But it seems that I cannot find the right way to do so. Any insights ?

Comment: And what is the problem exactly?

Comment: It doesnt work..     I have an error saying "PFObject doesnt have a member named deleteInBackground"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `deleteEventually()` with success before, together with `PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: YourClassName, objectId: YourObjectID)`.

If that works I wouldn't know why, but well :)

(as stated by Hector in this Parse Question (Objective-C): https://www.parse.com/questions/delete-row)

```
for object in objects {
    print(object["message"]
    var toDelete = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "sendMessage", objectId: object.objectID)
    toDelete.deleteEventually()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did see that indeed, however, I would rather have to skip finding out the objects' ID  before deleting.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can access the objectId without performing another Query. Since you retrieve the objects as an Array of PFObjects the objectId should be accessible as I did above (added example).

Comment: Would go with that. Thanks.    Will update you afterwards.

Comment: you got it!    Didnt work with "deleteEventually()", go figure; though worked like a charm with "delete()" using your method.   Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just keep in mind "delete()" is a synchronous method, and might freeze your app for long moment if the network connection is bad. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"sendMessage")
let username = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
    query.whereKey("messageSent", equalTo: username)
    query.whereKey("messageReceived", equalTo: self.nameLabel!.text!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError) -> Void in
        if  error == nil {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                 let deletemessage = object["message"] as! String
                    print(deletemessage)
                    object.delete()
                  }
             }
           } 
            else {
                    println("Error")
               }
     })
```

Comment: totally, tried checking the green sign too but it takes off the first answer that was given. Enlighten me on how to do so please.

Comment: It is unfortunate. I ll have to go with the first one given as both perfectly respond to my question. Sorry about that. I ll make sure to encounter a similar problem and ring you straight next ;)    Thanks again Ravi.